# Spartacus 3 session expired error on logout

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I'm getting “Your session has expired” error on logout after moving to Spartacus v3. It basically appears straight after selecting logout option from menu and persist on redirected login page until refresh. What can be the reason?

Comment: Hi Maria. There could be many reasons. Is this after an upgrade from 2.x to 3.0? Any errors on the browser console when you click on logout?

Comment: Yes,  it's started to happen after spartacus upgrade from 2.0 to 3.0. There were no any customization done on authorization.  In console it shows 'Invalid access token'.

Comment: Understood. Is there any more info on the console, maybe a stacktrace? Also, did you wipe out all of your node modules, refetch and rebuild?

Comment: Yes, I've tried that with no difference.

Comment: I added comment to the issue that is related to the problem and it'll be resolved with it.
Issue: https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/issues/10977
Follow ticket for updates.

Comment: Thanks @MarcinLasak

Comment: @MarcinLasak The ticket https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/issues/10977 has been closed. When I try this.auth.logout(); with import { AuthService } from '@spartacus/core';
redirect to login is not happening. Can you please help how to resolve in Spartacus 3.2